# Cómo conectarse a la base de datos MySQL de un servidor debian desde un script de python

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x

Sé cómo entrar en mi base de datos MySQL en mi servidor Debian que se ejecuta localmente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Puedo accederla en MySQL WorkBench:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me gustaría saber cómo hacer lo mismo desde un script python ETL. En efecto cuando intento lanzarlo obtengo:

```
(venv) C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Work\data-tools>py -m etl.task.crm_orders_exclude_from_statistics
2021-06-21 12:54:27.654131 - Connecting to database hozana_data...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\antoi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Users\antoi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Work\data-tools\etl\task\crm_orders_exclude_from_statistics.py", line 2, in <module>
    from etl.mysql.connect import db, db_name
  File "C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Work\data-tools\etl\mysql\connect.py", line 14, in <module>
    db = MySQLdb.connect(host=db_host,
  File "C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Work\data-tools\venv\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\__init__.py", line 130, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Work\data-tools\venv\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 185, in __init__
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError: (2002, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (10061)")
```

Antes hicé:

```
set  HOZANA_DATA_DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
set  HOZANA_DATA_DB_PORT=13306
set  HOZANA_DATA_DB_USER=root
set  HOZANA_DATA_DB_PASSWORD=root
set  HOZANA_DATA_DB_NAME=hozana_data
set  HOZANA_DATA_DB_ARCHIVE_NAME=hozana_archive
```

Tambien intenté con:

```
>>> MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost',
...                              port=13306,
...                              user='root',
...                              password='root',
...                              database='hozana_data')
```

Pero me devuelve:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Work\data-tools\venv\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\__init__.py", line 130, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Work\data-tools\venv\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 185, in __init__
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError: (2002, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)")
```

Tambien intenté:

```
>>> mysql.connector.connect(host='127.0.0.1', port=3306, user='root', password='root', database='hozana_data')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Work\data-tools\venv\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\network.py", line 574, in open_connection
    self.sock.connect(sockaddr)
ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Work\data-tools\venv\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\__init__.py", line 273, in connect
    return MySQLConnection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Work\data-tools\venv\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 107, in __init__
    self.connect(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Work\data-tools\venv\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\abstracts.py", line 1003, in connect
    self._open_connection()
  File "C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Work\data-tools\venv\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 350, in _open_connection
    self._socket.open_connection()
  File "C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Work\data-tools\venv\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\network.py", line 576, in open_connection
    raise errors.InterfaceError(
mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1:3306' (10061 No connection could be made because the target machin
e actively refused it)
```

Comment: ¿Has probado usar `localhost` en vez de `127.0.0.1`? Sólo por probar.

Answer (score 0):

No se muy bien como funciona tu script en python, yo para conectarme a una base de datos mysql desde python hago lo siguiente:

```
import mysql.connector

try:
    conexion = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',
                             port=13306,
                             user='root',
                             password='root',
                             database='hozana_data')

    print("Conexión correcta")

except (pymysql.err.OperationalError, pymysql.err.InternalError) as e:

    print("Ocurrió un error al conectar: ", e)
```

Comment: Acabo de probarlo con una bliblioteca differente pero persiste el error. ¿Supongo que me he equivocado de puerto o de host? Acabo de añadir la captura de pantalla de mi configuración en MySQL WorkBench

Comment: es posible, debería funcionarte, revisa el puerto, mysql usa por defecto el 3306